# Isotope Issue while toggling the div come space in bottom

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I am using the isotope masonry layout and the on click hiding and showing some info but on click of the element, there is some blank space at the bottom. Everything works fine on my local machine but not on the server.

[image: The layout looks like this after click]

```
 $(document).ready( function() {
 var $container = $('#container'),
    margin = 0,
    colWidth = function () {
        var w = $container.width(), 
            columnNum   = 1,
            columnWidth = 0;

        if (w >= 1025) {
            columnNum  = 4;
        } else if (w >= 769) {
            columnNum  = 3;
        } else if (w <= 768) {
          columnNum  = 2;
        }
        if (w <= 304) {
          columnNum  = 1;
        } 
        columnWidth = Math.floor(w/columnNum);
        $container.find('.item').each(function() {
            $(this).css({
                width: columnWidth - margin,
            });
        });
        return columnWidth;
    }


$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
  $container.fadeIn(1000).isotope({
    layoutMode : 'fitRows',
    itemSelector : '.photo'
  });
});



  $container.isotope({
     itemSelector: '.item',
      // layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    // layoutMode: 'fitColumns'
    resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
    // masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
     masonry: {  columnWidth: colWidth(),
                gutterWidth: margin }
  });

  var isotope = function() {
    $container.isotope({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      // layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    // layoutMode: 'fitColumns'
    resizable: false, // disable normal resizing
    // masonry: { columnWidth: $container.width() / 5 }
     masonry: {  columnWidth: colWidth(),
                gutterWidth: margin }
    });
  };



  // $container.isotope('shuffle'); // randomise for every new visitor
// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){  
  isotope();
});





  $items = $('.item'); // to reference methods on all .item divs later
  var iteamwidth = $items.width();

  $('.header').click(function () { // instead of registering the entire .item div (default use), only its .header div (child div) receives clicks

    var $previousSelected = $('.selected'); // necessary for switching
    var $prevImage = $('.selected .header img');
    var position =$(this).parent().position(); 
    var w = $container.width();

    // var curWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    $previousSelected.css("width", iteamwidth+"px");
    console.log(iteamwidth);
    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) { // use $(this).parent() (not $(this)), because the .header div is a child of the .item div

      $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
      $(this).parent().children('.maximised').hide();
      $(this).parent().children('.minimised').show();

      $(this).parent().css("width", iteamwidth+"px");
      // $(this).parent().children('.maximised').css("left", "0px");
      $items.find('.minimised, .header').removeClass('overlay'); // returns all .minimised divs to previous state after the .item is closed again

      //$container.isotope('layout');

    } else {





     // var thisCVTopPosition =$(this).offset().top;


     //      $('html, body').animate({
     //            scrollTop: thisCVTopPosition
     //        }, 200);








      $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');
      // $prevImage.css("width", "100%");
      //$previousSelected.children('.minimised').show();
      $previousSelected.children('.maximised').hide();

      $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
      //$(this).parent().children('.minimised').hide();
      $(this).parent().children('.maximised').show();

// console.log(w);

      if (w <= 767) {
          $(this).parent().css("width", ($("#container").width())+"px");
      } else {
        $(this).parent().css("width", ($("#container").width() - (iteamwidth+(margin*2)))+"px");
      }
      // $(this).children('.header img').css("width", "50%");


      $items.not('.selected').find('.minimised, .header').addClass('overlay'); // adds .overlay on each .item which is not currently .selected




    }

    $container.isotope('layout'); 
    // comment out to mimick old masonry behaviour

  });

});
```

Comment: Please provide a link or a jsfiddle.

Comment: Actually i solved it by calling methond of $container.isotope('layout'); in timout function.